# Getting a value from stored procedure which doesn't need parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net, sqldatareader

I have a stored procedure as shown below which retrieves the top 3 rows from my database.

**Stored Procedure**

```
USE [PaydayLunch]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetPastPlaces]    Script Date: 27/10/15 12:28:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPastPlaces]
AS
SELECT TOP 3* From Past_Places
  order by id desc
```

My DB has the following columns:

- ID
- Past_Place
- Month
- Click_Date

I want need to get the 'Months' value from my top row in my database but I don't know how to write this in my code behind as all solutions I find either populate a `gridview` or have parameters in which min doesn't and doesn't require them.

I need this value so I can use it in an `IF` statement in my view.

Just so you know that I do have to following code which uses another stored procedure to update table.

```
protected void BtnDecideForMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetRandomPlace", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Sets up the parameter
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OutputVar", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        // Opens the SQL connection & execute's the 'GetRandomPlace' sproc
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Reads the output value from @OutputVar in the sproc
        string place = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@OutputVar"].Value);
        conn.Close();

        // Populates the input field
        txtDestination.Text = place;
    }

    // Generates & updates past places table
    SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Past_Place"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)txtDestination).Text;
    SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Month"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
    SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Click_Date"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    SqlPastPlaces.Insert();
}
```

Comment: Check how to use a SqlDataReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed it using the following

```
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT        TOP (1) Month " +
            "FROM          Past_Places", conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                PastMonth.Text = reader["Month"].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Reader:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

command = new SqlCommand("TestProcedure", connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
connection.Open();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

List<Test> TestList = new List<Test>();
Test test;

while (reader.Read())
{
    test = new Test();
    test.ID = int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
    test.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
    TestList.Add(test);
}
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `ExecuteNonQuery()` which by its nature ignores any data you might get back. You need to either add output parameters to your procedure or use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) to get a data reader back and then read the information from that.